# how to change visual studio default language?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I installed visual studio code, I'm a beginner and struggled to change the language from French to English. When I searched online many people said that I needed to run  Visual studio installer but I can't find that and I do not have the tools option in the top bar.
Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Could you try these instructions: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales#_changing-the-display-language? Visual Studio is a different product from Visual Studio Code so those docs won't make sense for you

Comment: Thank you! It's my fault I mixed up visual studio code with visual studio.